# I am not at all able to solve this Bottom overflow by 283 pixels

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```dart
class Chest extends StatefulWidget {
  const Chest({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChestState createState() => _ChestState();
}

class _ChestState extends State<Chest> {
  //! Firebase SetUp

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  late String _email;
  late String _password;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              'BMI CALCULATOR',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal),
            ),
            Text(
              "WELCOME Mr.Dheer",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 100),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
              topRight: Radius.circular(60),
            ),
          ),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, right: 50, left: 50),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 95, 27, .3),
                        blurRadius: 20,
                        offset: Offset(0, 10),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  child: Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        TextFormField(
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _email = value;
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: "Email or Phone Number"),
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          enabled: true,
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _password = value;
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                              border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                              labelText: "PassWord"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40,
                ),
                Text(
                  'FORGOT PASSWORD',
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 30,
                ),
                Row(
                  // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    ReuseButton(
                      OwnTextButton: TextButton(
                        //! LOGIN FUNCTIONALITY
                        onPressed: () {},

                        // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/HomePage'),
                        child: Text(
                          'LOGIN',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      OwnBoxColor: Colors.orange.shade700,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    ReuseButton(
                      OwnTextButton: TextButton(
                        // ! REGISTER FUNCTIONALITY

                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/SignUpPage');
                        },

                        child: Text(
                          'Register',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      OwnBoxColor: Colors.orange.shade700,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 110,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Continue With Social Media',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    ReuseButton(
                      OwnBoxColor: Colors.blue,
                      OwnTextButton: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'Facebook',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    ReuseButton(
                      OwnBoxColor: Colors.black,
                      OwnTextButton: TextButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: Text(
                          'Gmail',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}

class ReuseButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReuseButton({required this.OwnBoxColor, required this.OwnTextButton});

  final Color OwnBoxColor;

  final TextButton OwnTextButton;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: OwnBoxColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
        child: OwnTextButton,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. wrap your inside `Expanded` Widget `Column` with `SingleChildScrollView()`. Just chnage your widget with my Widget/Code.

```
 Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                'BMI CALCULATOR',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 35,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                "WELCOME Mr.Dheer",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 100),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(60),
                topRight: Radius.circular(60),
              ),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(top: 80.0, right: 50, left: 50),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(225, 95, 27, .3),
                            blurRadius: 20,
                            offset: Offset(0, 10),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      child: Form(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            TextFormField(
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: "Email or Phone Number",
                              ),
                            ),
                            TextFormField(
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              enabled: true,
                              onChanged: (value) {
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                                labelText: "PassWord",
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 40,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'FORGOT PASSWORD',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'LOGIN',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Register',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 110,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Continue With Social Media',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'Facebook',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Gmail',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.red,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Your result Scrren-> [image]

Comment: Thanank you Ravindra, for your crystal clear answer :))

Comment: Welcome @KavachDheer glad to help you out enjoy your ride with flutter

Comment: Heyy Ravindra, can you help me in one more thing ..I want my image to take half the screen. How do I do that

Comment: Hello @KavachDheer can you tell me what do you exact want tell me in brif

Comment: On a blank screen I want to display a image .. but want it to take only half the screen not the full screen

Comment: Are you display image in above code ? if its yes where to display it?

Comment: No in some another project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239533/discussion-between-ravindra-s-patil-and-kavach-dheer).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in `SingleChildScrollView` like below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          // your rest code here...
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your code in ListView or SingleChildScrollView instead of the column :

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        children: [
          // your code
        ],
    );
  }
```